# log4j Custom Category Implementation

Tags: java, logging, log4j

What is the easiest way to implement a custom category class for log4j? Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Use log4j to send notifications using a custom built notification application.
2. Use the vanilla log4j library without having to fork and build a custom jar.

I want to overload the `info()`, `warn()`, `error()`, `fatal()` methods by adding 2 more parameters like this: `error(Object message, Throwable t, String alertLevel, String alertGroup)`.

I want to do this because I want to log and alert the same message in one call while still having the flexibility of logging and alerting in different levels.

I did many searches and looked through the apache log4j configuration tutorial and came up empty handed. I also realize there might be a better way to approach this. Can you someone show me the way please?

Comment: How is the custom app supposed to receive the notifications? Is it on the same machine only?

Comment: I should have been more clear. The notifications are sent to human users. The notification is sent via a RESTful web service call to the custom built alert service.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you are asking for, but you may want to look into [Mapped Diagnostic Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html).

Some information about can be found on http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#mdcz

Comment: Yeah, I have looked into both NDC and MDC. But they won't solve my problem of trying to make 1 call to log and send an alert notification at the same time. I'm somewhat OCD about minimizing non-domain code.

Comment: You could build a utility class which bundles the two operations into one: `class LogWithAlerts { public static error(Logger logger, Object message, Throwable t, String alertLevel, string alertGroup) { logger.error(...); alerter.alert(message, t, level, group); } }`. Alternatively, you could change your "custom built notification application" to use MDC to understand when to send alerts. Another avenue to explore is to take a look at how Log4j sends emails (SMTPAppender and https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AppenderSkeleton.html)

Comment: I like this solution. I was going to fork log4j and add the custom functionality. But I couldn't quite bring myself to do it because it kind of violates separation of concerns. Specifically, I realized if a log guard is used like logger.isInfoEnabled() and someone change the log level to error, then the notifications will not be sent. I think the utility class is a better idea. Thanks!

Comment: Good luck. Check out the effective java book's chapter on Forwarding class